# Pegar o children de um object

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Estou tentando adicionar e remover classes apenas à div que tem o hover, mas não consigo porque tenho 4 divs com a class .image.
Ocorre o mesmo em todas as divs.

Eis o código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').hover(function(e) 
        $(e).children('.button').addClass('animated zoomIn');
        $(e).children('.button').css("opacity", "1");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(e).children('.button').removeClass('animated zoomIn');
           }, 1000);
    }, function(e) { 
        $(e).children('.button').addClass('animated zoomOut');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(e).children('.button').removeClass('animated zoomOut');
           }, 300);
        $(e).children('.button').css("opacity", "0");
    });
});
```

Comment: Entretanto surgiu outro problema.
O remove.Class(...) não funciona. <pre>
setTimeout(function() { $(this).children('.button').removeClass('animated zoomIn'); }, 300);
</pre>

Comment: Eu referi esse problema do `this` dentro do `setTimeout` na minha resposta.

Comment: Tens razão, não reparei e já está resolvido. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando tens `$('.image').hover(function(e) {` o `e` é o evento que aconteceu. Esse objeto não tem `children`, o que procuras é o `this` que dentro dessa função é o elemento que recebeu o `hover`.

Dentro do `setTimeout` o `this` já é outro, por isso é melhor fazer cache do(s) elemento(s) fora desse `setTimeout`.

Assim precisas de mudar para:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').hover(function(e) {
        var $children = $(this).children('.button');
        $children.addClass('animated zoomIn').css("opacity", "1");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $children.removeClass('animated zoomIn');
        }, 1000);
    }, function(e) {
        var $children = $(this).children('.button');
        $children.addClass('animated zoomOut');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $children.removeClass('animated zoomOut').css("opacity", "0");
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que ao invés de usar:

```
 $(e).children('.button').addClass('animated zoomIn');
```

Você deveria usar:

```
 $(this).children('.button').addClass('animated zoomIn');
```

O `this` nesse caso faz referência ao elemento em que atualmente foi capturado o evento `hover`. O parâmetro `e` é na verdade um objeto, contendo várias informações do evento aplicado.

Veja meu exemplo funcionando:

```js
$(function () {
       $('.image').hover(function () {
          $(this).children('.button')
               .addClass('red');
       
      }, function () {
           $(this).children('.button')
               .removeClass('red');
      });
});
```

```css
.image{
     height:100px;
     width: 100px;
     background-size: 100% auto;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.red{
  background-color: #800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Imagem%20de%20Teste&w=150&h=150);">
  <button class="button">Hello</button>
</div>

<div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Imagem%20de%20Teste&w=150&h=150);">
  <button class="button">Hello</button>
</div>

<div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Imagem%20de%20Teste&w=150&h=150);">
  <button class="button">Hello</button>
</div>
```

## Atualização

Como o contexto da função anônima usada pelo `setTimeout` não está vinculado ao elemento do jQuery, é necessário referência-lo dentro de `setTimeout.

O @Sergio explicou na resposta dele como resolver esse problema, definindo uma variável referenciando o seletor do jQuery e usando ela dentro de `setTimeout`. Mas, se preferir, o jQuery oferece uma solução através de uma função chamada `$.proxy`.

Veja como ficaria o código:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').hover(function(e) {

```
    $(this).children('.button').addClass('animated zoomIn').css("opacity", "1");

    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animated zoomIn');
    }, this), 1000);

}, function(e) {

    $(this).children('.button').addClass('animated zoomOut');

    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $children.removeClass('animated zoomOut').css("opacity", "0");
    }, this), 300);
});
```

});

O `$.proxy` tem como finalidade aplicar vincular um contexto para a função. Ou seja, você define através dele "quem" vai ser o `this` usado pela função.

Exemplo:

```js
$(function ()
{
    setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
         alert(this.name);
    }, {name: "Wallace"}), 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Porque removeste a lógica do `setTimeout`? também há um `$(e)` para corrigir lá dentro.

Comment: @Sergio eu não coloquei `setTimeout` :|

Comment: Entendi @Sergio. O problema também é que o `setTimeout` da pergunta não iria funcionar com o `this`.